# Как дебажить функции стандартной библиотеки?

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, отладка

Я так понимаю, что нужны `.c/.cpp` файлы, но где их взять? Есть специальные пакеты для этого? Какие команды использовать?

Comment: Лучше опишите конкретную проблему, которая у вас случиласть - стандартная библиоткека, штука довольно обширная. Кроме того, она в основном состоит из шаблонов, исходники которых имеются в наличии (и дебаггер туда заскакивает сам)

Comment: @gbg просто хочу дебагером зайти в `__libc_start_main`, например

Comment: Поставьте на нее breakpoint в своей любимой IDE и заходите сколько влезет.

Comment: @gbg у меня нет ни исходника, ни IDE; где взять исходник?

Comment: Ну, если вам так нравится управлять gdb из консоли - вот ваш случай
https://www.jamestitcumb.com/posts/gdb-debugging-basics

Comment: @gbg я знаю, как использовать gdb. Видимо, вы не прочитали мой вопрос

Comment: Откройте ссылку и посмотрите. Там другой такой же энтузиаст залезает в ту функцию, которую вы хотите.

Comment: @gbg там прямым текстом написано "libc-start.c: No such file or directory.". Вопрос в том, где взять этот файл

Comment: Очевидно, что нужно скачать пакет с исходником. Конкретное название пакета зависит от дистрибутива, но обычно, там присутствуют буквы "src"

Comment: https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/csu/libc-start.c

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin -  так можно оказаться в глупом положении, если версия установленной libc не совпадет с той, что выложена на github

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin есть ли пакет для убунту, поставив который, дебаггер сможет заходить в этот файл?

Comment: @user492263 - https://lmgtfy.app/?q=ubuntu+glbc+source

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/28372/416190

Comment: Кроме собственно исходников, еще понадобятся отладочные символы. А лучше сразу линковать с отладочной сборкой стандартной библиотеки.

Comment: @user7860670 где всё это взять? готовых команд не могу найти

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000335/how-to-use-debug-version-of-libc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте установить пакеты из списков, полученных с помощью:

```
apt-cache search libc6-dbg
apt-cache search libc6-dev
apt-cache search libstdc++ | grep dbg
apt-cache search libstdc++ | grep dev
```

Где :

1 - пакеты с отладочными символами libc6

2 - пакеты для разработки с libc6

3 - пакеты с отладочными символами libstdc++

4 - пакеты для разработки с libstdc++

Вы, в принципе, можете установить все, из выданных списков, но можно выбрать пакеты для своей или целевой архитектуры.
Если ваша целевая архитектура - не x86, то не забудьте установить для нее компилятор. GCC также может быть использован для кросс-компиляции.

P.S. Ну а вообще отлаживать такие библиотеки, по-моему, пустая трата времени, они хорошо оттестированы, и скорее всего ошибка на вашей стороне.

Comment: Чем отличается пакет "для разработки" от пакета "с отладочными символами"?

Comment: @user492263 Первые содержат заголовочные файлы для включения их в ваш проект, вторые содержат непосредственно отладочные символы.